# how to connect to IBOutlet or IBAction in base class

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller, interface-builder

I have a base view controller class which inherits from `UIViewController` and an inherited class from the base `viewcontroller` class. Now I have a nib whose file owner is the inherited class but all my actions and outlets are in the base class. Is it even possible to connect the action\outlet in the nib file to that in the base class?

Comment: Yes. Are all your files in the same project in Xcode?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I'll be basically explain it by [example](https://github.com/abbood/IBOutlet-inheritance):

Define a base class (let's call it `BaseViewController`) and assign it a `UITableView` IBoutlet in the .h file:

```
//  BaseViewController.h
@interface BaseViewController : UIViewController    
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;    
@end
```

Define two children classes (ie `FirstChildViewController` and `SecondChildViewController`):

```
// FirstChildViewController.h
@interface FirstChildViewController : BaseViewController
@end

// SecondChildViewController.h
@interface SecondChildViewController : BaseViewController
@end
```

Now to make either (or both of) the children classes use the iboutlet of the base class, simply drag the referencing outlet to the property definition in the base class .h file.. and that's it!

[image]

[here](https://github.com/abbood/IBOutlet-inheritance) is a complete project that illustrates this.

Answer (score 8):

If the base class is in a Swift framework, then sometimes Xcode 7 will not see the outlets, even if the base class and its outlets are public. In this case the workaround is as follows:

1. In IB set the control to use the base class
2. Connect the outlets
3. In IB set the control to use the derived class

IB will show "!" next to the outlets as if they are missing, but there will be no errors at runtime.

If someone has a better workaround, let me know!

Comment: Can you explain a bit more detailed how to do this stuff?

Comment: @c0d3Junk13: Open Storyboard. Show Identity Inspector. Select control. Set its class to base class. Connect outlets. Select same control and set class to derived class. Ignore warnings.

Comment: hmm.. this seems hackish.. is it allowed? or is it something that will break later on

Comment: This is indeed hackish. Luckily Xcode 7.3 seems to always find the outlets so hopefully you won't need to ever do this.

Comment: Seven years later, this solution is still applicable in xcode 14.1

Answer (score 7):

Two ways to accomplish this:

1)

do it programmatically (i.e. in code)

First declare your outlets in the base class.

and then assign your outlets via code in your inherited class.

and

2)

You can also assign your outlets and actions in your XIB file.  Xcode knows about inherited outlets and actions from base classes.